# Course-of-values induction, according to Kleene IM (1952)

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, natural-deduction, formal-proofs, meta-math

I'm having troubles with exercise *162a in *"Introduction to Metamathematics"*, by S.C. Kleene, 1952.

The ask is to prove:

(1) $ \vdash A(0) \& \forall x [\forall y (y \leq x \Rightarrow A(y)) \Rightarrow A(x')] \Rightarrow A(x)$

where x and y are variables distinct from each other, y is free for x in A(x) and does not occur free in A(x).

Kleene's hint is to proof:

(2) $ \vdash A(0) \& \forall x [\forall y (y \leq x \Rightarrow A(y)) \Rightarrow A(x')] \vdash \forall y (y \leq x \Rightarrow A(y))$

and

(3) $ \vdash \forall y (y \leq x \Rightarrow A(y)) \vdash A(x)$

from which (1) follows. He also suggests that (2) can be proofed using the induction rule, which requires the proof of:

(4) $\vdash A(0) \& \forall x [\forall y (y \leq x \Rightarrow A(y)) \Rightarrow A(x')] \vdash \forall y (y \leq 0 \Rightarrow A(y))$

and of

(5) $\vdash A(0) \& \forall x [\forall y (y \leq x \Rightarrow A(y)) \Rightarrow A(x')], \forall y (y \leq x \Rightarrow A(y)) \vdash \forall y (y \leq x' \Rightarrow A(y))$

I managed to prove (3), but I'm struggling with (4) and (5). Can you help? Thanks

Comment: The verb is "prove" not "proof", "proved" not "proofed", etc.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint for (4)*: by induction with $P(y) := (y \le 0 \to A(y))$.

$A(0)$ by assumption; thus, using $P \to (Q \to P)$ and MP, we get $(0 \le 0) \to A(0)$.

Assume $P(y)$ and prove $P(y+1)$. But $P(y+1)$ is $(y+1 \le 0 \to A(y+1))$ and $\lnot (y+1 \le 0)$, because $y+1$ is a successor and we know that no successor can be equal to $0$.

Thus, using tautology $\lnot P \to (P \to Q)$ and MP we get $P(y+1)$.

Thus: $P(y) \to (P(y+1)$; $y$ is not free in the assumption and we can generalize it to get: $\forall y (P(y) \to (P(y+1))$. With $P(0)$, by Induction: $\forall y ((y \le 0) \to A(0))$.

---

*Hint for (5)*

Using the second part of the fist premise instantiating the leading quantifier we have: $∀y(y≤x \to A(y)) \to A(x')$ and using 2nd premise and MP we get: $A(x')$ and thus $y=x' \to A(y)$. From which: $y=x' \vdash (y \le x' \to A(y))$.

If $y≤x'$ we have $y \le x \lor y=x'$. Thus, assuming $y \le x$ from 2nd premise we have $A(y)$ and so $y \le x \to A(y)$ and also $y \le x \vdash (y \le x' \to A(y))$.

Thus, from $y \le x \lor y=x'$ by cases, we get: $y \le x' \to A(y)$

Comment: Sorry but it's not clear how you get $y=x' \vdash (y \leq x' \rightarrow A(y)) $ from $A(x')$ in the first half of hint for (5)

Comment: @Lorenzo - the trick is the same as 4: use $P \to (Q \to P)$. If $A \to B$, then $A \vdash B$. Thus with $\vdash B \to (C \to B)$ we have $A \vdash (C \to B)$

Comment: Two observations (I'm kind of new to logic, so please bear with me)

1) When you say "... $A(x')$ thus $y = x' \to A(y)$" I believe you are using axiom for equality (Axiom 23 in Kleene's book). If that is the case, I think it's a bit unusual for Kleene to use something he has not yet introduced in the book without even mentioning it.

Comment: 2) When you say "Thus from $y\leq x' \lor y = x'$ by cases we get: $y \leq x' \to A(y)$", I believe you also use $\vdash A \lor \lnot A$. If this is the case, please bear in mind that in Kleene's book this is only true in the classical system, not in the intuitionistic system, whilst the deduction we are talking about is marked as valid in both systems.

Comment: To 1): yes, it is equality and is Replacement. Theorem 24.(b), page 184.

Comment: @Lorenzo - To 2): no, we do not need LEM. We have (page 187) that $y \le x'$ is defined as $y \lt x' \lor y=x'$. And 138a (page 188) $y \lt x' \equiv y \le x$.